# Playing HTML5 embedded sound on Android

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-audio, html5-animation

I have a Flash animation with sound that I converted to HTML5.
When I play it in a WebView or open it with the device browser, there is no sound.

I've tried several sound formats with no success.

I used [www.html5test.com](http://www.html5test.com) to see the browser compatibility and it supposed to support mp3.

[image]

Is is possible? 
Any ideas how?

I am using Android 4.0.4

Comment: Is the device's media volume muted?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here Embed Background Audio in Android >= 2.3 Browser

```
<audio id="audio1" controls="controls" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" >
   <source src="scene1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   <source src="scene1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

it's work for me :)